# How can I disable locations in Android 11(API 30) using adb shell command

Tags: adb, shell, android-11

The following commands do not disable location services on API 30. Although they do work on other API levels.

```
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -network
```

They do not throw any error message, but they do not turn off the location services either.

Comment: I assume the main problem is that `location_providers_allowed` is deprecated since API 19. According to the [API doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED) it should be still present in 30 however the doc also states `Do not rely on this value being present or correct`.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 11 -

to enable, I use:

```
adb shell settings put secure location_mode 3
```

and to disable, use:

```
adb shell settings put secure location_mode 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).